# Error: node stack overflow when using msprep

Tags: r

I have been struggling with this for a while, and have already tried `options(expressions=500000)` and `...\Rgui.exe --max-ppsize=500000`, and they are not fixing it, so I think it must be a problem with the code, but I can't work out what.

I am trying to use msprep for a dataset with about 1900 cancer patients, with competing risks including death.

```
mscurrent_data <- msprep(time = c(NA, NA, NA, "T_f", "T_b","T_S",  "T_v", "T_P", "T_n"), 
                         status = c(NA, NA, NA, "f_status", "b_status",  "S_status", "v_status", "P_status", "n_status"),
                         data = current_data, 
                         trans = tmatrix,
                         start=list(state=start_state, time=start_time),
                         id = current_data$trialno, 
                         keep = covs)
```

I get Error:

> node stack overflow

and can't work out why.

Thanks very much in advance for any help.

Comment: Please use `library(.)` call to load the needed packages.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out! I had to remove the variable labels from the start_state variable before opening the data in R. No idea why that worked, but I came across this question by someone else, who had the same problem as me ([link](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Problems-with-including-lefttruncation-in-mstate-td4695653.html)), which made me start thinking about the actual values/attribute lengths.

Thanks anyway, and I hope this is helpful for other people.